# Swift Framework: Use System Header in Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks

I'm creating a new swift framework, that contains a class that I implemented in Objective-C. This works fine, but it needs sqlite3.h. I managed to create a module map, so that I can use sqlite3.h in my Swift classes already. However when I try to use it in the Objective-C header class with `@import sqlite3;` I get the error "Module 'sqlite3' not found.

For reference, I created the module map for sqlite3 similar to "ifaddrs" in:
https://ind.ie/labs/blog/using-system-headers-in-swift

And again, it works fine in Swift classes, unfortunately not in the Objective-C ones. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the reference about creating module map in swift. It is what I need to do for my own little framework. Regarding using C in ObjC, is that possible you can just directly using C in ObjC as you import sqlite3 header directly?